# Django CMS - can't reorder children plugin

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a plugin timeline with many children event plugins. For some reason, when I try to drag and reorder the event children plugins, I get a red line that appears and I'm not allowed to move the children plugin.

Child Plugin is made up of:

- Title
- Description
- Date
- Image

I can't find any posts about this, why does this happen and is there any way to fix this?

(Parent) Timeline Plugin

```
require_parent = True
parent_classes = [...classes that exist for sure...]

allow_children = True 
child_classes = ['TimelineEvent',]
```

(Child) Timeline Event Plugin

```
require_parent = True
parent_classes = ['Timeline',]
```

Comment: This appears to be either not django-cms or a custom plugin for django-cms. Can you pleae provide more details regarding the package that you are using?

Comment: Any updates on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. The reason turned out to be that the name of the parent class in `parent_classes` was incorrect. In my case it should have been "RowPlugin" instead of just "Row". So check your actual plugin names in cms_plugins.py files and what did you put in "child_classes" and "parent_classes".